# Integrating a teradata database with django models framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, teradata

We have an external teradata reporting database which we want to create a frontend for generating and querying using django.

I've gotten relatively far on just using a direct ODBC connection to the DB and running queries and displaying them on the website, but the further I get into it the more evident it is becoming that I really need to be using the django models framework.

My question is does anyone have any experience or insight in how to integrate a teradata database into a django web app?

For instance, I am displaying data using django-tables2 as it allows the tables to be generated not only using a queryset, but also a list of dictionaries which works great for me. Now I have come to adding filtering using django-filters package, and it seems it can only be done using an queryset object and nothing else.

Would be grateful for any advice you may have to offer!

Comment: I went through something similar last year, trying to bypass Django's ORM with a custom ORM.  It was a headache and I realized life would be much easier to just do it the way `Django` wants you to.  I think I tried "faking" the querysets using `RawQuerySets` but eventually I ran into problems with those trying too since they have limitations.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there isn't much I can do about changing the DB source so am stuck with teradata for now. Am still looking around for any kind of hack to get around it.

Comment: I'll check some old code later tonight and post it here if I think it may be useful.

Comment: @chaylins Did you create complete ORM for teradata by any chance?

Comment: @just10minutes no I didn't. I downloaded the Python Teradata API from Teradata and just wrote my own package using raw queries to complete what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a "database utilities" library I put together for my Django app.  The back-end was Postgres, but it should be adaptable to Teradata.

Take a look at the logic in the `get_data_qs()` function.  That's the one I used to try to create `QuerySets` using the `__in` filter trick, which should convert the result set to a `QuerySet`.  Not sure how far this will take you, but something to play around with.

**dbUtils.py**

```
from django.db import connection
from collections import namedtuple

# TO-DO: Handle non-ASCII characters (Python default encoding is ASCII)

# Return data as a RawQuerySet object (list of objects)
def get_data(myobjects, sp_signature, params):
    # IMPORTANT: Model field names must match column names in DB
    resultset = myobjects.raw('select 1 as id, * from ' + sp_signature, params)

    # Check if resultset has any rows
    try:
        test = resultset[0] 
    except IndexError:
        return myobjects.none() # return empty queryset ("not myobjects.none()" == True)

    # Return result set
    return resultset

# Return data as a single model object
def get_data_pk(myobjects, sp_signature, params):
    resultset = get_data(myobjects, sp_signature, params)

    # If there is a result set, return the first instance
    if(resultset):
        return resultset[0] 

# Return data as a QuerySet object (first column in resultset must be the model PK
def get_data_qs(self, sp_signature, params, pk_fieldname = None):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        # Use default PK if not provided
        if(not pk_fieldname):
            pk_fieldname = self.model._meta.pk.name

        # Create "IN" filter
        myfilter = pk_fieldname + '__in' 

        # Execute query and apply filter to convert to QuerySet        
        cursor.execute("select * from " + sp_signature, params)
        return self.filter(**{ myfilter: (x[0] for x in cursor) }) 
          # TO-DO: This (**) may need looking at due to Python 3 conversion

    finally:
        cursor.close()

# Return data as a non-objectified result set (list of rows)
def get_data_raw(sp_name, params):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:        
        cursor.callproc(sp_name, params)
        return_data = namedtuplefetchall(cursor) # Format as result set (list of tuples)
        cursor.close()

    return return_data

def save_data(sp_name, params):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:        
        cursor.callproc(sp_name, params)
        return_data = cursor.fetchone() # Store any output
        cursor.close()

    return return_data

# Return all rows from a cursor as named tuples (i.e. rows with field names)
def namedtuplefetchall(cursor):
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    nt_result = namedtuple('Result', columns)

    return [
        nt_result(*row) 
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
```

Comment: is this dbutils supposed to be replacing the ORM model for Teradata?  I am in need to use teradata as default database where I can create models and view data on Django. Any suggestions/lead will help me a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "replacing the ORM model for Teradata".  This library should be DB-agnostic and lets you run read data from a DB connection using stored procedures (`sp_signature`).  If you access your data from a TD system using SPs, it should work.  It could also be modified to use views or any other SQL statement that retrieves data -- this is the key line: `myobjects.raw('select 1 as id, * from ' + sp_signature, params)`.  You just build your `SELECT`statement and pass it to the raw() method of your object manager.